# I am unable to provide a valid PEM file to HaProxy despite validating the PEM file and installing the self-signed certificate in the correct places

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy, self-signed-certificate

**I will post my private key in its entirety because it is an example for development and debugging purposes.**

This is the process by which I have created my PEM file:

https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out example.dev.key 1024
sudo openssl req -new -key example.dev.key -out example.dev.csr
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in example.dev.csr -signkey example.dev.key -out example.dev.crt
sudo cat example.dev.crt example.dev.key | sudo tee example.dev.pem
```

This is a self-signed certificate. The PEM file looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Ok now that I have this, I validated it as follows. ALL KEYS HAVE R/W PERMISSIONS FOR ALL USERS:

https://www.ssl247.com/kb/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting/certificate-matches-private-key

```
openssl x509 –noout –modulus –in example.dev.crt | openssl md5

openssl rsa –noout –modulus –in example.dev.key | openssl md5

openssl req -noout -modulus -in example.dev.csr | openssl md5
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 I installed the key in /etc/ssl and /etc/haproxy:

http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#selfsigned-openssl

```
$ cd /etc/ssl
$ ln -s example.dev.crt `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in example.dev.crt`.0

ajorona@ajorona-box/etc/haproxy$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  8 17:55 errors
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1795 Dec  9 12:28 example.dev.pem
```

Now my haproxy.cfg file has the following lines:

```
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/example.dev.pem
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
```

I validate my haproxy.cfg:

```
ajorona@ajorona-box:~/server $ haproxy -c -f haproxy.cfg 
[ALERT] 343/123930 (114320) : parsing [haproxy.cfg:29] : 'bind *:443' : unable to load SSL certificate from PEM file '/etc/haproxy/example.dev.pem'.
[ALERT] 343/123930 (114320) : Error(s) found in configuration file : haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 343/123930 (114320) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
ajorona@ajorona-box:~/server $ sudo haproxy -c -f haproxy.cfg 
[ALERT] 343/123933 (114444) : parsing [haproxy.cfg:29] : 'bind *:443' : unable to load SSL certificate from PEM file '/etc/haproxy/example.dev.pem'.
[ALERT] 343/123933 (114444) : Error(s) found in configuration file : haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 343/123933 (114444) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

I've spent a full day on this, I can't really figure out why this is happening...

Comment: How much of the original information is redacted? How many commands are reconstructed and not actual output? Also your first article uses RSA 1024 in 01/2018, I wouldn't trust anything in there...

Answer (score 0):

did you manage the certificate problem. I get the same result, my certs exist and the access to them is also open (no restrictions for haproxy to read the directory with ssl cets). All certs are in PEM format and contain the key, crt. Any help is highly appreciated.